# using negative conditions within regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

Is it possible to use negative matches within gsub expressions?
I want to replace strings starting by `hello` **except** those starting by `hello Peter`

```
my-string.gsub(/^hello@/i, '')
```

What should I put instead of the `@`?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If a string starts with "hello", where does it end? You don't mean just the string "hello", I suppose.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think "strings starting by" means any string that begins with that pattern and not specify what comes after that ... any suggestion to make it more clear and I'll edit it for the record.

Comment: The starting part is clear. What is not clear is, where it ends. Are you simply interested in the strings "hello" or strings that start with "hello" and continue for some length? I thought you wanted the latter, and if that is the case, NeX,s answser will be appropriate. If you wanted simply "hello", then Michael's answer is good.

Comment: I mean the latter, though a simple "hello" (as it's not followed by "peter") should match as well. Maybe I'm missing something, but apart from the blank space position, both answers seem correct to me ... Michael's answer catches strings of any length and words number for me.

Comment: Michael will work kind of find but will miss a couple of cases. `We are martians and we say 'hello peter' all the time` will match. `hello` alone won't match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you want a negative lookahead:

```
>> "hello foo".gsub(/hello (?!peter)/, 'lala ') #=> "lala foo"
>> "hello peter".gsub(/hello (?!peter)/, 'lala ') #=> "hello peter"
```

Comment: +1, _negative lookaheds_ are not so intuitive. Nice to see a simple example.

Comment: Oh yes that's it :)

Thank you Michael!

Comment: Nice, another down vote without explanation. If you have a factual problem with an answer, why not give feedback?

Comment: Michael, see Nex comment in the question comments. A small fix will do. Anyway, it was completely useful for me, thanks!

Comment: dgilperez: I saw the comment, but I don't think it warrants a down-vote. Anyway, we are not even sure it was his and it doesn't really matter in the end as long as your question got answered.

Answer (score 2):

As Michael told you you need a negative lookahead.

For your example is something like:

```
my_string.gsub(/^hello(?! peter)( .*|$)/i, '')
```

This will replace in cases like:

```
"hello"
"hello Mom"
"hello "
"hello Mom and Dad"
```

And will ignore things like:

```
"hello Peter"
"hello peter"
"hellomom"
"hello peter and tom"
```