# Regexp: Any characters except sequence

Tags: ruby, regex

> [^abc]    Any single character except: a, b, or c

But how can I make regex for any characters except sequence `abc`

So, something like that

```
"Hello abc awesome world".scan /[^(abc)]+/
```

Will return "Hello " and " awesome world".

PS: And it is not about splitting the string

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5504272/946850

Comment: Also related, more closely perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6180556/946850

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is called [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), in your case you'll want to use negative lookahead. I'm not sure about the exact syntax in Ruby, but something along `(?!abc)` might work. Note that the lookaround doesn't consume any input, so you'll need to have this followed by any pattern that you do want to match. Perhaps `(?:(?!abc).)+` is what you're looking for?

Comment: Saved me muchos time. Was doing `(?!abc).+`, which did the negative lookahead for a whole sequence of characters. This one appears to do it on a character by character basis, which didn't even occur to me. Now all is well and happy. Gracias!